# Adding Custom Views To Screen Manager Gives Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

Currently I am developing a Kivy app and I am trying to make a start on some of the page navigation.

In my app.py I have imported all my different view files that I will need to navigate through.

I am right now attempting to make a start by adding my homepage class to my screen manager. But sadly I keep getting this error `kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget.` and I am hopeless as to what is causing the issue.

Here is the code commented

```
#various page testing imports
from kivy.app import  App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

#importing all page files into app
from view_Controllers.homepage import homepage
from view_Controllers.createWallet import create_A_Wallet
from view_Controllers.recoveryPhrase import recovery_Phrase, confirm_Phrase
from view_Controllers.createPDF import createPDF

#importing screen manager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


''' will need to decide on how to transition views here'''
class paperGap_Wallet(App):
    def build(self):
        #creating screen manager
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        #instance of homepage view
        self.homepage = homepage()

        screen = Screen(name="Homepage")
        screen.add_widget(self.homepage)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)
        self.screen_manager.current = "Homepage"

        return self.screen_manager


app = paperGap_Wallet().run()
app.run()
```

I will also show the code im running for the homepage, its very simple just 2 buttons and a label.

```
class homepage(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        #setup for box layout
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.spacing = 30
        self.padding = 80

        #Ui element instantiations
        welcome_Label = Label(text="Welcome to Paper Gap Wallet",
                              size_hint=(None, None),
                              height = 180,
                              width = 330,
                              pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5},
                              font_size=42,
                              )



        create_Wallet_Button = Button(text='Create a New Wallet',
                                size_hint=(None, None),
                                height=70,
                                width=380,
                                pos_hint={'center_x':0.5},
                                font_size=25,
                                background_color = (0,0,1,1)
                                )

        exit_Button = Button(text='Restore Previous Wallet',
                                size_hint=(None, None),
                                height=70,
                                width=380,
                                pos_hint={'center_x':0.5},
                                font_size=25,
                                # background_color = (0,0,1,1)
                                )
        #adding UI elements to root
        self.add_widget(welcome_Label)
        self.add_widget(create_Wallet_Button)
        self.add_widget(exit_Button)
```

Any help is much appreciated, Ive a feeling it has to do with the class type I am adding to the screen manager but not entirely sure

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code and ran it just so as i could backward trace it however, eh voila! , it worked fine here is the code.
I ran it using kivy '2.0.0', python 3.7.9, in VsCode. I heard kivy '2.0.0' supports python 3.9 though

```py
#various page testing imports
from kivy.app import  App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

#importing all page files into app
# from view_Controllers.homepage import homepage
# from view_Controllers.createWallet import create_A_Wallet
# from view_Controllers.recoveryPhrase import recovery_Phrase, confirm_Phrase
# from view_Controllers.createPDF import createPDF

#importing screen manager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class homepage(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        #setup for box layout
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.spacing = 30
        self.padding = 80

        #Ui element instantiations
        welcome_Label = Label(text="Welcome to Paper Gap Wallet",
                              size_hint=(None, None),
                              height = 180,
                              width = 330,
                              pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5},
                              font_size=42,
                              )



        create_Wallet_Button = Button(text='Create a New Wallet',
                                size_hint=(None, None),
                                height=70,
                                width=380,
                                pos_hint={'center_x':0.5},
                                font_size=25,
                                background_color = (0,0,1,1)
                                )

        exit_Button = Button(text='Restore Previous Wallet',
                                size_hint=(None, None),
                                height=70,
                                width=380,
                                pos_hint={'center_x':0.5},
                                font_size=25,
                                # background_color = (0,0,1,1)
                                )
        #adding UI elements to root
        self.add_widget(welcome_Label)
        self.add_widget(create_Wallet_Button)
        self.add_widget(exit_Button)


''' will need to decide on how to transition views here'''
class paperGap_Wallet(App):
    def build(self):
        #creating screen manager
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        #instance of homepage view
        self.homepage = homepage()

        screen = Screen(name="Homepage")
        screen.add_widget(self.homepage)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)
        self.screen_manager.current = "Homepage"

        return self.screen_manager


paperGap_Wallet().run()
# app.run()
```

However, i have some advise:

1. Use KivyLanguage,i.e kv string or kv file, it makes alot of stuff easy i.e
   For the HomePage class do like so;

```py
# declare the HomePage class
class HomePage(Screen):
    pass

# Then add in the kv_string 

kv = '''
<HomePage>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 30
        padding: 80

        Label:
            id: welcome_Label
            text: 'Welcome to Paper Gap Wallet'
            size_hint: None, None
            height: 180
            width = 330
            # size: 330, 180
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
            font_size: 42

        Button:
            text: 'Create a New Wallet'
            size_hint: None, None
            # height: 70
            # width: 380
            size: 380,70
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}

        Button:
            text: 'Restore Previous Wallet'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 380,70
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
            font_size: 25
            # background_color = (0,0,1,1)


'''   
#dont forget to load this kv string, unless its in a kv file with the same name as the 'App' class 

Builder.load_string(kv)


# Then add your homepage like this;

class PaperGap_Wallet(App)
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(HomePage,name='homepage')
        return sm

# and then run like this;

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PaperGap_Wallet().run()
```

That way your HomePage will be a screen Object, and you won't have to manually add all those widgets(Labels and Buttons).
NOTE: A Screen Object is a RelativeLayout, which is just another layout of some sorts so i feel like you should work within it.
I have an app am building too and i have done it that way it works well for me.

2. Name your classes with first letters Capital,i.e

   class HomePage() instead of class homepage()

i donno that naming convention's name but it makes code readable and follow the rules even when they may make no immediate difference.

Comment: I realised that my error has to do with the fact that my Hompage() class was in a seperate file to my App() class. When i reimplemented the same App() code within the same file as my Homepage() class, the code worked perfectly.

Comment: Is there any chance you know why this is the case. I am clueless. I myself being a Java programmer from craft would like to have each of my classes in separate files. Is there a way of getting my screenmanager to work without having to have all my code bunked into one single file.